# Check Youtube live chat is available before embedding

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

Is it possible to check the availability of a Youtube live stream's chat programmatically?

I'm successfully embedding the chatbox using the following:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=ecHbnqUuqeE&embed_domain=localhost"
  width="100%"
  height="100%">
</iframe>
```

The issue is this embeds a chatbox with the text `Chat is disabled for this live stream.`

If you go to the original stream on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecHbnqUuqeE), you'll see there is a chatbox that was enabled. I believe Livestream creators can toggle whether or not the chatbox can be embedded.

My question is, can I check whether the chat is enabled prior to embedding it in my site?